# Why are the drawings grouped together when they should be separate?

Tags: f#

I'm facing a problem that I don't understand the reason and I don't know how to solve it.

I create a form to display differents shapes.

Here is the code, in a module call  "Affiche" :

```
let mutable decalX = 0
let mutable decalY = 0
let calculPoint (x : int) (y : int) = 
    Point( 10 * x + 50 + decalX, 10 * y + 50 + decalY)

let blackPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2.0f)

let afficheForme (pts : int list list) (f : Form) =
    List.iter (fun (s : int list) -> f.Paint.Add (fun e -> e.Graphics.DrawLine (blackPen, calculPoint s.[0] s.[1], calculPoint s.[2] s.[3]))) pts
    decalX <- decalX + 500
    if decalX = 2000
    then decalX <- 0
         decalY <- decalY + 500
```

I work on shapes, extracting different pieces to display them.

Here is the code use to display polygones (simplified)

```
let (shapes : int list list list)  = Poly.compute points
List.iter (fun (pts : int list list) -> Affiche.afficheForme pts form) shapes
```

Here is what I should get and the first line, and what I have on the second line
[image]

The shape of the second line is displayed at the place where the last shape of the first line should be.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `Form` type works, but from your description we know that the functions you're passing to `f.Paint.Add` aren't getting called until after all your calls to `Affiche.afficheForme` are complete, meaning `decalX` is equal to `2000` at that time. Try making `decalX` and `decalY` parameters to your functions so that it's easier to reason about what their value is in a given scope.

Comment: i find it amusing how `blackPen` is actually red

Comment: @Travis Sunderland >> Problem solved thank you, !